# Unable to get CFIF expression to compare 2 equal values correctly

Tags: coldfusion, expression

For the life of me I can't get `CFIF` to give me a true result when using the `EQ` operator with 2 equal fields . Below is the CF code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="sales_contact_id">
    <cfoutput query="rc.getPartnerContacts">
        <cfif rc.getPartnerContacts.id EQ rc.getPartner.sales_contact_id>
            <cfoutput><option  value="#rc.getPartnerContacts.id#" selected="selected">#fname# #lname#</option>
            </cfoutput>
        <cfelse>
            <cfoutput><option  value="#rc.getPartnerContacts.id#">#fname# #lname# #rc.getPartner.sales_contact_id#</option>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfif>
    </cfoutput>
</select>
```

I put the `#rc.getPartner.sales_contact_id#` into the option text to show the value of the variable.

And this is the HTML output:

```
<select name="sales_contact_id" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">David Elliott 2</option>
    <option value="2">James Knight 2</option>
    <option value="3">Fred Bloggs 2</option>
    <option value="4">John Doe 2</option>
    <option value="5">Jane Smith 2</option>
</select>
```

The value of the `rc.getPartner.sales_contact_id` field is 2 which the same as the id field for the 'James Knight' record in the `rc.getPartnerContacts recordset`.  The `CFIF` statement should be true for the James Knight record so that this option is the default within the drop down list.  I've tried using `val()`, I've tried subtracting one from the other and then using a `CFIF EQ 0` and still won't work!

I'm sure that this is a really simple mistake but I can't see it!!!

Comment: It must be the framework making some slight changes.  There was a slight change for to reduce the amount of code pasted, but that wasn't it.

Comment: Check `rc.getPartnerContacts.id.getClass().getName()` and `rc.getPartner.sales_contact_id.getClass().getName()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A facepalm moment - The `<cfoutput>` within a `<cfoutput>` caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a formatted comment.  When in doubt, look at your data.

```
 <cfdump var="#rc.getPartnerContacts#">
 <cfoutput query="rc.getPartnerContacts">
 <cfif rc.getPartnerContacts.id EQ rc.getPartner.sales_contact_id>
 yes
 <cfelse>
 no ID is #id# and sales contact id is #rc.getPartner.sales_contact_id#
 </cfif>
 <br>
```

Comment: .. and if there is no obvious, visual difference, examine the characters and compare the ascii values.